# Iphone: View will appear method does not calls when using popover controller

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, nsuserdefaults, uipopovercontroller

I am using a pop over controller in a view that contains table view. The image is as below:

[image]

Each index take me to its view and that view contains radio button for single selection.Image:

[image]

Now i am not able to get the value to my main view which contains the popover because the popover is not dismissed and i ma not able to call the view will appear method for the main view.

how can i pass the value of option selected in the textview of main view.

Thanx in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the popover delegate is set to the popover controller the implement `- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController`

and from there call a method on the mainviewcontroller to set whatever you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

You should link `uipopovercotrnooler` to its `delegate`. then you can use 2 of the methods:

`- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController`
`- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009307